# How to display message from contact form on the main page

Tags: php

I have PHP contact form and I want the Message sent or failed message to be displayed inside the main page.. I have  tag after the submit button with id="notification" I want the message from send.php to be displayed inside of it.

My code is:

```
<form method="post" action="send.php">

        <label>Name</label>
        <input name="name" placeholder="Type Here">

        <label>Email</label>
        <input name="email" type="email" placeholder="Type Here">

        <label>Subject</label>
        <input name="subject"  placeholder="Type Here">

        <label>Message</label>
        <textarea name="message" placeholder="Type Here"></textarea>

        <button id="submit" name="submit" type="submit">Dergo</button>

        <h3 id="notification" align="center" style="font-color:green;"></h3>
    </form>
```

Send.php code:

```
<?php
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $subject = $_POST['subject'];
    $message = $_POST['message'];
    $from = 'From: KontaktFormular'; 
    $to = 'albanianboy2@gmail.com';
    $headers = "From:" . $email . "\r\n";
    $headers .= "Reply-To: ".$email."\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n"; 

    $body = "From: $name\n E-Mail: $email\n Message:\n $message";

if(@mail($to,$subject,$body,$headers))
{
  echo "Mesazhi juaj u dërgua me sukses";

}else{
  echo "Gabim! Ju lutemi provoni përsëri.";
}
?>
```

Comment: where is the javascript client side code?

Comment: you need to have the query push the message to the notification id. I would change that to a div instead of an h3. where is your javascript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put your code in a PHP file.
Your code:

```
<?php session_start(); ?>

 <form method="post" action="send.php">

    <label>Name</label>
    <input name="name" placeholder="Type Here">

    <label>Email</label>
    <input name="email" type="email" placeholder="Type Here">

    <label>Subject</label>
    <input name="subject"  placeholder="Type Here">

    <label>Message</label>
    <textarea name="message" placeholder="Type Here"></textarea>

    <button id="submit" name="submit" type="submit">Dergo</button>

    <h3 id="notification" align="center" style="font-color:green;">
     <?php
           if(!empty($_SESSION["notification"])){
                echo $_SESSION["notification"];
                unset($_SESSION["notification"];
            }
      ?>
    </h3>
</form>
```

Your send.php file:

```
<?php

session_start();

$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$subject = $_POST['subject'];
$message = $_POST['message'];
$from = 'From: KontaktFormular'; 
$to = 'albanianboy2@gmail.com';
$headers = "From:" . $email . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: ".$email."\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n"; 

$body = "From: $name\n E-Mail: $email\n Message:\n $message";

if(@mail($to,$subject,$body,$headers))
  {
   $_SESSION["notification"] =  "Mesazhi juaj u dërgua me sukses";

  }else{
   $_SESSION["notification"] = "Gabim! Ju lutemi provoni përsëri.";
   }
 header("location: YOUR_PHP_FILE_WITH_THE_FORM ");
 ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change this part of your code:

```
}else{
  echo "Gabim! Ju lutemi provoni përsëri.";
}
```

to:

```
}else{
      header('Location: mainpage.php?msg=1');
    }
```

Then on main page, you can have:

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['msg']) && $_GET['msg'] = 1)
    {
?>

<h3 id="notification" align="center" style="font-color:green;">
    Gabim! Ju lutemi provoni përsëri.
</h3>

<?php
    }
?>
```

Comment: that's one way to do it, but having jquery manipulate the message is better in terms of browsers and having the code up to date and modern although this example is perfectly fine.

Answer (score 0):

The message

```
$notification = "put your message";
```

The Javascript:

```
// Appeding notification to Body
$('#notification').html($notification);
```

Do this where you do your php check.

Put this css on top:

```
#notification{
    display: none;
}
```

Setup your div

```
<div id="notification">
```